# Attachments in Cases UI Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: mobile, snap-ins

Is there an easier way to achieve the same "attachments" functionality without having to fully build the SF UI from scratch. And leverage our existing use of the Snap in SDK.

This would mean less development time to achieve the same result.

1. Is there a working demo project (instead of links to documentation) that can be studied and analysed that will help expedite development?
2. Does SF have plans to include attachments to Case Management SDKs (Android and iOS)? And when if yes?
3. Is there a way to inherit from CaseUI classes to include this functionality?